# How do I retrieve all titles, and display all descriptions and thumbnails from a specific playlist

Tags: javascript, api, youtube, youtube-api

I'm sure this is an easy question but I am new to JavaScript. The code at this link [retrieve-youtube-video-title](http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2010/01/retrieve-youtube-video-title.html) shows how to retrieve a single youtube thumbnail, description and title etc and it works. But how can I get the code to  display the same info from a playlist feed? And can i use this feed URL:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/719DC9340EXAMPLE?alt=json-in-script&format=5&...
```